# Запись навигационных точек в БД

Tags: postgresql

Имеется система, к которой подключается навигаторы. Каждая точка с навигатора приходит примерно раз в 4 секунды(может чуть реже). Поэтмоу поток большой и количество устройств только растет.
Все точки должны быть сохранены в БД. Плюс каждая из них отправляется на внешнюю систему и получает ответ от нее на каждую точка. Поэтому и возник вопрос как правильно записывать такой поток в БД?
Сейчас я открываю на это отдельное соединение БД и шлю все данные только через него по одному запросу за раз. Но мне кажется, что это не совсем верный подход

Comment: Если запрос "подготовленный" и вы выполняете только его execute с новыми данными (которые передаются в самом execute или возможно в bind перед этим), то подход в общем то правильный. грузить блоками, усложняя запрос вряд ли будет быстрее.

Comment: Плохо, я Dapper использую(( Ладно будем уберать из этого потока Dapper.